# Adding/Removing classes on table data onclick

Tags: javascript, css, addclass, removeclass

I would like to add a class for a table cell that matches the hover color onclick or on select of the cell.

I have this javascript (that doesnt work currently):

```
$('#tblContainer').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // Remove highlight
    $this.closest("tr").find("td.guidelines").removeClass("guidelines");

    // Add it to this one
    $this.closest("td").addClass("guidelines2");
});
```

With these 3 main classes (guidelines, guidelines2- the class I want it to change to, and guidelines:hover):

```
table.rubrictable td.guidelines {
    background: #FFF; 
    padding: 6px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:9pt;
    font-style:plain;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666666;
    width:150;
    background: #FFF; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left top , #E6E6E6, #FFF); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#E6E6E6), color-stop(100%,#FFF));
}
table.rubrictable td.guidelines2 {
    background: #3C0; 
    padding: 6px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:9pt;
    font-style:plain;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666666;
    width:150;
}
table.rubrictable td.guidelines:hover {
    background:#3C0;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tblContainer" class="rubrictable">
    <th class="dimensionstitle">ROWS (Dimensions)</th>
    <th class="level">Delicious<br />
      4</th>
    <th class="level">Good<br />
      3</th>
        <th class="level">Needs Improvement<br /
          2</th>
        <th class="level">Poor <br />
          1<a href="#" title="Remove this performance level."></a>
          </th>
        <th class="dimensionstitle">COMMENTS</th>
        </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dimensions" nowrap="nowrap">Number of Chips

      &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Chocolate chip in every bite</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Chips in about 75% of bites</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Chips in about 50% of bites</td>
    <td class="guidelines"Too few or too many chips</td>
    <td class="dimensions"><img src="Icons/edit-green.gif" width="16" height="16" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dimensions">Texture&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Chew</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Chewy in middle, crisp on edges</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Texture either crispy/crunchy or 50% uncooked</td>
    <td class="guidelines">Texture resembles a dog biscuit</td>
    <td class="dimensions"><img src="Icons/edit-green.gif" width="16" height="16" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you can see an example here in my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rja3n/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You've put your `click()` handler on the table itself, so when you do `$this.closest("tr")`, it's looking for an element that is an ancestor (not a child) of the table and that is a `tr`.  It won't find it.

Just change the click declaration to

```
$('#tblContainer td').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

As JacobM stated, you need to use the td on the cell.

`$('#tblContainer td').click(function() {`

However, your table has a class for all the options you would like to be selectable. That means you could use `#tblContainer .guidelines` instead.

`$('#tblContainer .guidelines').click`

I also believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/sZenj/1/

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, but I have one more question for you, I need this to work in several tables.  I updated this fiddle, [http://jsfiddle.net/sZenj/2/] to show a table container over the original table.  How do I make THIS work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're goal here is. Can you try explaining again?